# How to convert temperature to an ON-OFF state

Tags: circuit-design

Suppose I want to build a simole circuit that reads the temperature as a voltage from the sensor. If the voltage gets below a certain value, turn the heater on (1). Else, turn the heater off (0).  How would I build this circuit?

Comment: A comparator might work for this

Comment: @mike65535 might be a good idea to add some hysteresis, making that comparator something like a *Schmitt Trigger*.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bimetallic strip thermostat would be the perfect tool for this job. If it's not, why?

Comment: they make "arduino" temp modules with digital outputs and a trim pot for about $2; includes an opamp and a proper circuit (triggering)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A bimetallic strip thermostat provides on-off switching at a user defined setpoint. Source: [Science 2012](https://2r7science2012.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/thermostat-bimetallic-strip-6/).*

Your question is very vague and it is not clear (1) what the application is, (2) how large the sensor can be, (3) how precise a switching point you require, (4) whether hysteresis (difference between turn-on and turn-off point) is required or acceptable, (5) what the operating voltage is, (6) the switching current capability and (7) whether you are looking for a digital solution or what.

You could build a simole circuit using just a thermostat of the type used in home heating temperature control. The principle of operation is shown in Figure 1 but in practice they are a little more tricky and use a toggle action so that once tripped the contacts open or close very quickly to minimise arcing on the contacts.

Comment: This is actually for an Designing Dihital Systemsbeginning class.

Comment: That almost answers point (1).